# External references are not found when I try to publish via MSBuild on the build server

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

When I try to publish my "Web Site project" via MSBUild on our build server, the process fails because it cannot find external references. 
I went to look at the build agents and I can see that the files that copied are only the *.dll.refresh files but not the dlls.

I have tried to copy these files via the BeforeBuild and BeforeMerge targets in my website.publishproj but they simply do not copy (I have inspected the source folders after the build and only find the *.refresh), this is what I do:

```
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild"> 
            <ItemGroup>
                 <MyCustomFiles Include="..\ObjectLibrary\AllinLibrary2.dll"/>
                 <MyCustomFiles Include="..\ObjectLibrary\Infragistics45.Web.v14.1.dll"/>
                 <MyCustomFiles Include="..\ObjectLibrary\Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.v8.3.dll"/>
                 <MyCustomFiles Include="..\ObjectLibrary\Infragistics35.WebUI.Shared.v8.3.dll"/>
                 <MyCustomFiles Include="..\ObjectLibrary\Infragistics45.WebUI.Shared.v14.1.dll"/>
                 <MyCustomFiles Include="..\ObjectLibrary\Infragistics45.WebUI.WebDataInput.v14.1.dll"/>
                 <MyCustomFiles Include="..\ObjectLibrary\Infragistics45.WebUI.WebHtmlEditor.v14.1.dll"/>
                 <MyCustomFiles Include="..\ObjectLibrary\Infragistics45.WebUI.WebSchedule.v14.1.dll"/>
             </ItemGroup>

             <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyCustomFiles)" DestinationFolder="bin"/>
</Target>
```

How can I have these files copied so the server can find the dlls and ultimately succeed building/publishing?

Note that when I publish from Visual Studio (2015) it does succeed. Also, if I run MSBuild command from my local workstation, it does succeed as well, it is only when it runs from the build server that it simply fails.

Here are the MSBuildArguments from my build definition, just in case:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=MsBuild2015  /p:Configuration="Release" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:AspnetMergePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools"
```